# override __getattr__ to return None for non-existent **nested** attributes in python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-class

**Background**

If you do something like

```py
print(inst.a)
```

and attribute `a` does not exist in `inst`, you'll get an `AttributeError` as expected

If `inst` is an instance of a class where you've overridden `__getattr__`, you can return `None` if the attribute is not found instead.

```py
def __getattr__(self,name):
    return None
```

This works pretty well, since `__getattr__` is only called if `__getattribute__` failed to find the attribute. The problem is, if you have a nested attribute lookup with something like this

```py
print(inst.a.b.c)
```

then you'll receive an error like the following

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'b'
```

that's because we returned `None` from the first attribute lookup for `a`. The returned value of `None` is then checked to see if it has an attribute `b`

**Question**

1. So is there anyway to override `__getattr__` and/or `__getattribute__` in such a way that it would work for nested attributes?
2. Is there a way to abort subsequent attribute lookups, when the first one fails? Problem is, I don't seem to be able to know if there are any subsequent attribute lookups from within `__getattr__`, as I only get the current attribute `name`
3. Or is there anyway to know if this is the last in a set of attribute lookups? If I had that knowledge, then I can easily update this to support an arbitrary nested attribute lookup.

I'm only interested in solutions that would work by overriding `__getattr__` and the like

Comment: "So is there anyway to override `__getattr__` and/or `__getattribute__` in such a way that it would work for nested attributes?" No, that is fundamentally **not how that expression works**.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You could say that fundamentally __gititem___ doesn’t work in a way that supports nested access. But you can override it to work well with nested dicts for example. That’s what I’m curious about. If there’s a way to get around that for __getattr__. I offered a couple possible options that would indirectly offer what I’m after, if those are possible. Any thoughts on those?

Comment: no, `__getitem__` cannot do the equivalent of this, if you return `None` from `__getitem__`. You could always return some item that you know returns some item which will have either `__getitem__` or `__getattr__`.  But you cannot "abort" a chain, other than by throwing an exception, but I don't think that's what you want. If you want to keep track of any state, you are going to have to return some object that does that. I'm not sure anything outside of trying to inspect the call stack and other heroic hacks like that would be able to tell you if it is the last in a chain.

Comment: So, what exactly do you mean by " But you can override it to work well with nested dicts for example." regarding `__getitem__`, exactly? It certainly doesn't make dict's have the behaviors you are describing

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think I came up with a solution. Just need to implement and test out. Rather than subclass a dict, I'll use the collections.abc to define my own class, say NestedDict. I'll only set its .store value to a dict() when actually written to. An empty __init__ will set its value to None. This way I can return NestedDict() rather than None from my __getattr__ override, which will recursively call my NestedDict.__getattr__ down the chain of attributes